# Is this recurrence relation solvable?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider the following recurrence relation:

\begin{equation}
\gamma C_{m,n}+n\alpha C_{n,m}+ \beta \{C_{n+1,m}+ n C_{n-1,m}\}=EC_{n,m}
\end{equation}

where $\gamma, \alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. The question is to find $C_{n,m}$ and $E$.

If $\gamma=0$ I know how to solve it. One can ignore index $m$ and the problem would be a one variable recurrence relation. In this case, one set of solution for example is $E=-\frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha}$ and $C_{n}=(\frac{-\beta}{\alpha})^{n}$. There are other sets of solutions as well.

The problem gets complicated when $\gamma$ is not zero. I was wondering if a solution exists.

Comment: A solution other than $0$, I guess.

Comment: The $C_{m,n}$ certainly makes this less amenable to standard techniques. Have you tried generating functions?

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, I have. It gets really nasty!!! I am still working on it tho.